# Can I Use The Same Linq Code to Query for Different Conditions?

Tags: linq, where-clause, dry

I am repeating the following linq code with a slightly different WHERE section each time.

I'd like to follow the DRY principle and only specify the View Model once. Is there a way to reuse the same query and specify the WHERE condition dynamically?

I've had a look round here on SO and come across some similar questions, but I can't find an answer that makes sense to me.  Am I missing something obvious?

**First Example**

```
List<CMSSummary> summaryList = db.CMSUpdates
    .Where(i => i.PublishDate.Year == year)  // only this line is different
    .AsEnumerable().Select(i => new CMSSummary
    {
        CMSObjectID = i.CMSObjectID,
        Title = i.Title,
        SubTitle = i.PublishDate.ToString("ddd dd MMM"),
        ToolTip = i.Title,
        Summary = i.Summary,
        MainImage = i.MainImage,
        ItemURL = i.URL,
        FullURL = "/mockup/cmspage/" + i.URL,
        HTMLClasses = ""
    }).ToList();
return summaryList;
```

**Second Example**

```
List<CMSSummary> summaryList = db.CMSUpdates
    .Where(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm))  // only this line is different
    .AsEnumerable().Select(i => new CMSSummary
    {
        CMSObjectID = i.CMSObjectID,
        Title = i.Title,
        SubTitle = i.PublishDate.ToString("ddd dd MMM"),
        ToolTip = i.Title,
        Summary = i.Summary,
        MainImage = i.MainImage,
        ItemURL = i.URL,
        FullURL = "/mockup/cmspage/" + i.URL,
        HTMLClasses = ""
    }).ToList();
return summaryList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(note: I did not test this code(takes too much preparation), so there might be some errors)

You have two options.

The first is to use the fact that [the `Where` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) accepts `Expression<Func<CMSUpdate, bool>>` as the predicate. So, you just have to create your own method that accepts `Expression<Func<CMSUpdate, bool>>` as argument and uses that argument to build the query:

```
List<CMSSummary> SummaryList(Expression<Func<CMSUpdate, bool>> predicate){
    return db.CMSUpdates.Where(predicate)
    .AsEnumerable().Select(i => new CMSSummary
            {
            CMSObjectID = i.CMSObjectID,
            Title = i.Title,
            SubTitle = i.PublishDate.ToString("ddd dd MMM"),
            ToolTip = i.Title,
            Summary = i.Summary,
            MainImage = i.MainImage,
            ItemURL = i.URL,
            FullURL = "/mockup/cmspage/" + i.URL,
            HTMLClasses = ""
            }).ToList();
}
```

and call it with the predicate:

```
SummaryList(i => i.PublishDate.Year == year)
SummaryList(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm))
```

(you might need to change it to pass `db` as an argument).

The other option is to use the fact that the `Where` extension method returns `IQueryable<CMSUpdate>`, and create a method that takes that `IQueryable<CMSUpdate>` from the `Where` method and apply the rest of the query to it:

```
List<CMSSummary> ToSummaryList(IQueryable<CMSUpdate> query){
    return query.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new CMSSummary
                {
                CMSObjectID = i.CMSObjectID,
                Title = i.Title,
                SubTitle = i.PublishDate.ToString("ddd dd MMM"),
                ToolTip = i.Title,
                Summary = i.Summary,
                MainImage = i.MainImage,
                ItemURL = i.URL,
                FullURL = "/mockup/cmspage/" + i.URL,
                HTMLClasses = ""
                }).ToList();
}
```

And call it with the half-query:

```
ToSummaryList(db.CMSUpdates.Where(i => i.PublishDate.Year == year))
ToSummaryList(db.CMSUpdates.Where(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm)))
```

Comment: thank you, perfect explanation, I've got it now, and +1 for offering 2 ways :)